# JavaScript: why can't I chain Array.prototype.filter with .push()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, chaining, method-chaining

If `Array.prototype.filter` returns an array, why can't I invoke `push()` on this return value immediately?

Example:

```
var arr = ["a", "ab", "c", "ad"];
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(elmnt) { return elmnt.indexOf("a") > -1; });
// result: ["a", "ab", "ad"]

arr2.push("aaa");
// result: ["a", "ab", "ad", "aaa"]
```

Ok so far.

But what about chaining that `push()` call to the `filter()` call?

```
var arr = ["a", "ab", "c", "ad"];
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(elmnt) { return elmnt.indexOf("a") > -1; }).push("aaa");
// result: 4
```

Why does chaining `filter()` and `push()` result in the number of elements that I would expect, rather than an array of those elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not with what `filter()` returns, instead it is with what `push()` returns.

**[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** returns the new length of the array, and not the array itself.

So when you do:

```
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(elmnt) { return elmnt.indexOf("a") > -1; }).push("aaa");
```

`arr2` will be assigned the new length of the array (which happens to be 4 in your case), and not the new array as such.

A modified version that'll do what you want would be:

```
var arr = ["a", "ab", "c", "ad"], arr2;
(arr2 = arr.filter(function(elmnt) { return elmnt.indexOf("a") > -1; })).push("aaa");
// now arr2 is ["a", "ab", "ad", "aaa"]
```

Comment: Of course, of course... one of those moments where your own SO question makes you feel stupid.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use `concat();`

```
var arr = ["a", "ab", "c", "ad"], arr2;
(arr2 = arr.filter(function(elmnt) { return elmnt.indexOf("a") > -1; })).concat("aaa");
// now arr2 is ["a", "ab", "ad", "aaa"]
```

Answer (score -1):

now run the above code and see the result/error.

Analyze the difference between your answer before and after running the code

Q2. correct the code so that method chain starts working

```
function filterOddNumbers(num) {
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`const evenNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].push().filter(filterOddNumbers);`